can we use tanh activation function to detect outliers?
Can we use tanh activation function to detect outliers ?
Does my image below true for dataset outliers (after training model with tanh activation function) ?


This will not be the case in most situations I can imagine or that I have encountered. Perhaps there is a way of setting up the model to do this, but I'm not aware of one.
Think for example your model's final layer is to predict a temperature within some range (say from -20 degrees to 20) and you take the output of tanh and multiply it by 20 to get your output. What in your image look like potential outliers would just be cases where the temperature is closer to -20 or 20. If these are outliers or not depends on your data, not on where they fall in the tanh function.
